# Dormand Prince Multi Step Algorithm

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For a system of differential equations solved by Dormand Prince Algorithm, is the step size changed differently for each equation or (h) is changed the same for all equations each step according to the error ? 
And also what is the best error tolerance to choose as epsilon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Runge-Kutta method and thus classified as a one-step method. It is also an embedded method as it provides and uses two approximations of different error order.

And yes, for a coupled system you have to use the same step size on all coupled components. What you can adapt is the norm by introducing weights for the components in case their typical magnitudes are too different.